# Как вставить большой класс в класс-фрагмент?

Tags: android, java

Был разработан большой класс, теперь его нужно впихнуть в этот код:

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

 public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment(){}
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что конкретно вас смущает? С фрагментом работают точно так же как и с Activity, единственное - у него свой интерфейс(xml), к которому мы получаем доступ через inflater. Например получить объект кнопки в фрагменте - Button button1= (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1). Если необходимо получить контекст или Activity, к котором находиться фрагмент - getActivity(). Вопрос не понятен).

Comment: Спасибо, не работают некоторые элементы, к примеру        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

Comment: Спасибо, с getActivity() очень помогли. Первый день на фрагментах.
Осталось только понять как подогнать под фрагмент строку 
        final Activity activity = this;